# OpenTelemetry TLS error "first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry

I am using OpenTelemetry k8s operator as well as the Jaeger operator. I am trying to enable TLS between the two as well as my Quarkus application and I am running into some problems. The error that I am receiving is `"ServerHandshake" failed: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"`.

My configuration is as follows:

```
receivers:
  otlp: 
     protocols:
        grpc:
          tls: 
            cert_file: /cert/location/tls.crt
            key: /cert/location/tls.key
exporters:
  jaeger:
    endpoint: jaeger-tls-collector:14250
      tls: 
        ca_file: /cert/location/ca.crt
        cert_file: /cert/location/tls.crt
        key_file: /cert/location/tls.key
```

My Quarkus application.properties contains the following:

```
quarkus.application.name=MyAppOne
quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://open-telemetry-microservice-collector:4317
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled TLS for your receiver:

```
receivers:
  otlp: 
     protocols:
        grpc:
          tls: 
            cert_file: /cert/location/tls.crt
            key: /cert/location/tls.key
```

But Quarkus uses http protocol:

```
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://open-telemetry-microservice-collector:4317
```

It should be https, because TLS is enabled:

```
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=https://open-telemetry-microservice-collector:4317
```